# HighCharts Currency in Maps

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

In my HighCharts Map, I have values that are currency. On the hover, I'd like them to appear as $, but they just appear are raw numbers.

Here's what I have so far

```
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'map',
                    name: 'Orders $',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#BADA55',
                        },
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.name}',
                    },
                    allAreas: true,
                    data: this.model,
                },
            ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be enough to set `pointFormat` property in `tooltip` configuration object:

```
  tooltip: {
    ...,
    pointFormat: '{point.value}$'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xp71L0jv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat